# django python social auth get facebook profile picture

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I'm using Django and I'm trying to create a profile page which shows the user's facebook profile picture. I am using Python Social Auth package, and also managed to log in via Facebook.

Now the problem is I'm not able to show the Profile Picture. Through my Django admin panel, I'm able to see the user's facebook Uid and data, but I can't seem to be able to access them through the template {{ user.uid }} (something like that).

I'm not sure how I can do it and I have been googling all day and people seem to be talking about the pipeline. I don't understand the docs exactly and it has been really confusing.

Everyone seems to talk about using pipeline and adding it into the settings and then they just stop after that. But I'm trying to get it to show on the template.

I hope you guys could give some assistance. Thank you.